Value of gst and income tax
For country India
Let I am registered gst tax payer under composition scheme. I am a trader selling burnt clay bricks. Rate of composition gst will be 1% for me. I get 1 crore 40 lakhs in current account registered with this composition gst. So my gst will be 140000Rs. Now how much income tax will this amount 1 crore 40 lakhs fetch i.e. I need to pay
